Transparent Render makes object blue
I'm rendering this object animation which is a tangram puzzle that starts as a box and moves to different shapes. Whenever I render it in cycles (with transparent turned on) using FFmpgvideo - RGBA and encoding as Quicktime and QT Animation as a codec I receive this as a result.

If I render it out under any other setting besides RGBA it looks normal. Here's the compositor screen as well as I don't have a mix shader included which I found online as a culprit for issues dealing with transparency. There are duplicate shapes that are in the same location, just with their viewport and render key framed off until later in the animation in case that could be the reason.
It kinda looks like a face orientation that got exported, but when I adjust the face orientation the same thing still happens. Am I missing something?


It looks as if a share on https://blend-exchange.com/ , following the instructions there, might help us track this down, keep it minimal, and pack any images you have used in textures, etc ( it doesn't look as if you have any of those)

I would suggest exporting your animation in PNG files for animation with transparency. The only downside is that it can be harder to work with, though a lot of software let you manipulate them similar to video clip. DJV is amazing for visualizing

Thank you, uploaded the file here: 

And yes, I will export them as PNG if I can't find an answer for the issue, but it's definitely not my preferred workflow for something like this!
